# Enforce Objective-C object to use a certain delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

Is there a way to enforce an object to use a certain protocol (Not answer to a certain protocol - rather it "uses" a protocol in its calls)?

This syntax is the "opposite"

```
id <aProtocol> object;
```

will ensure that "object" answers to the methods of "aProtocol", but I would like to pass an object around which uses "aProtocol" in order to ensure that the callee will respond.

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? Do you mean to ensure that `object` responds to all methods in `<aProtocol>`? Then `id <aProtocol>` is **the** syntax.

Comment: I mean pass an object which defines a protocol. not one that uses it

Comment: Objects don't define protocols. Programmers do. If you want an object that **implements** that protocol, then that's `id <TheProtocol>`.

Comment: Protocols are not defined as part of classes in any case. They stand alone. There is no way to know externally whether an object will call a given protocol. I believe your design here must change; this is likely not a solvable problem in any object-oriented language.

Comment: I have a view class with a collection view inside it. This view is reused multiple times. I don't want to change the data source for each view controller which contains this view (as well as this views delegates). The view controllers which contain the view are not the views datasource necessarily. the base view controller reuses the same code for each data source. (imaging a NSFetchedResultsController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a matter of how you write the class. Have the objects call the methods in the delegate protocol at appropriate times, and voila, you've made the object use the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
-(void) callMethodWithObject:(id <aProtocol>) object;
```

So the passed in object is 'expected' to respond to aProtocol.

Or do you mean making a class that implements the protocol like this in the header file?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <aProtocol>
```

{
}